# Get previous month date range

Tags: php, datetime, date, strtotime, mktime

I need help getting the previous months full date range in the following format: Y-m-d

I have successfully been able to get "this" months full date range but not the "previous" months full date range.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
    $last_month_first_day=strtotime('first day of last month');
    $no_of_days=date('t',$last_month_first_day);
    $date_value=$last_month_first_day;
    for($i=0;$i<$no_of_days;$i++)
    {
        echo date('Y-m-d',$date_value)."<br>";
        $date_value=strtotime("+1 day",$date_value);
    }
```

This code will print what you want..

First Date:

```
echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime('first day of last month'));
```

Last date:

```
echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime('last day of last month'));
```

Comment: This works for me but it is printing out each date of the month. Is there a way to have it just show the "first" and "last day" instead of all of the dates in between. Example: '2011-12-01' & '2011-12-31'?

Comment: Check now ...Just First and Last date in most easy way to achieve..:)

Answer (score 14):

This gets the job done correctly:

```
echo date('Y-m-01 - Y-m-t', strtotime('previous month'));
```

Here is the proof: http://ideone.com/L82ZW

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
$month = 2;
$lastday = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month+1, 0, 2012);
$firstday = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1, 2012);

$end = date("Y-m-d", $lastday);
$start = date("Y-m-d", $firstday);
```

> The last day of any given month can be expressed as the "0" day of the next month.
>   http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php

Answer (score 0):

```
// works with PHP 5.3 or later
$today = new DateTime();
$thisMonthFirstDay = $today->setDate($today->format('Y'), $today->format('m'), 1);
$previousMonthLastDay = $thisMonthFirstDay->sub(new DateInterval('P1D')); // substract 1 day

$daysInLastMonth = $previousMonthLastDay->format('d');

for($i=1; $i<=$daysInLastMonth; $i++) {
    $num = ($i < 10) ?'0'.$i :$i; // add zero in front if < 10
    echo $previousMonthLastDay->format('Y-m-') . $num. "\n";
}
```

Comment: This works for me but it is printing out each date of the month. Is there a way to have it just show the "first" and "last day" instead of all of the dates in between. Example: '2011-12-01' & '2011-12-31'?

Comment: Yes there is a way to do that.